# ConcurrentModificationException in Spark

Tags: apache-spark

Below is my code:

```
scala> spark.sql(s" select * from $da_table_nm a where metric_date=date_add(date_sub('$order_dt','$start'),3)").repartition(num_partitions).createOrReplaceTempView("temp")

scala> spark.catalog.cacheTable("temp")

scala> spark.sql(s"insert into table $cortex_table_nm partition(year,month,day) select a.*, year(metric_date)as year, month(metric_date)as month,day(metric_date)as day from temp a")
```

I am getting this error in Spark 2.0:

```
ERROR LiveListenerBus: Listener EventLoggingListener threw an exception
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
```

I am calling these three lines in a loop to process data from different dates (metric_date) in the above code.  The job progresses in spite of this error but after processing a few days, it hangs and fails.  Any idea on how I can avoid this?

Comment: can you try in this way? instead of `insert into` query, 

    `val tempDf = spark.sql(s"select a.*, year(metric_date)as year, month(metric_date)as month,day(metric_date)as day from temp a");` then 
       `tempDf.write.mode("overwrite").partitionBy("year", "month_day").saveAsTable($cortex_table_nm)`

Comment: Can you try with Spark version 2.1.1? I also had some issues as above with early versions of Spark 2.x.